# What does 'a family of dominant rational maps' means?

Tags: algebraic-geometry

https://arxiv.org/abs/1609.02119

Here is Sileverman and Call's paper. In page 1, they consider a 'smooth irreducible quasi-projective curve $T/\mathbb{C}$ and a family $$ f_T : \mathbb{P}^N_T \rightarrow \mathbb{P}^N_T$$ of dominant rational maps'.

My question is, what is $\mathbb{P}^N_T$? And what is $f_T$? First, I thought that this is just a notation which means $\{f_t : t \in T \}$ but they said $f_T$ is also a dominant rational map and they considered a dynamical density of this map! But I don't know what this map and the domain are.

Comment: A family $X\to T$ can be thought as a $T$-scheme. So $f_T$ makes perfectly sense in the category of $T$-schemes.

Comment: I don't have any knowledge of schemes. Can you explain more elementary? Is it impossible?

Comment: Well, I guess you can look at any introduction to schemes (e.g. Eisenbud-Harris).. and actually you should, since the paper seems pretty much written using such a language.

Comment: Thank you Cla. But now my goal is just understanding what is the question. Is it also need a language about that?

Comment: When you say "curve $T/\mathbb{C}$, you are saying that $T$ is endowed with an intrinsic map to $Spec\,\mathbb{C}$. Now, a scheme $X/Y$ is just a generalisation of this concept to arbitrary schemes, i.e. there exists an intrinsic morphism $X\to Y$. Then you can define the category of $Y$-schemes, and in particular you can make sense of morphisms of $Y$-schemes and properties among them.

Comment: I'm now little confused but okay, I need to learn about scheme. Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First of all, let me agree with Cla on the fact that you should check some basic introduction to schemes in order to work with the paper you mention. Having said that, I'll try to give you some intuition regarding $\mathbb{P}_T^N$ and $f_T$ using as little scheme theory as possible.

When you say "a curve $T\vert_{\mathbb{C}}$" you are referring to an abstract curve $T$ together with a map $\pi\colon\,T\to\mathrm{Spec}(\mathbb{C})$. (Since $\mathrm{Spec}(\mathbb{C})$ is merely a point, this only means that locally the functions of your curve have a structure of $\mathbb{C}$-algebra.)

Now, given such a map, the projective space $\mathbb{P}_T^N$ is defined as the fiber product $\mathbb{P}_T^N=\mathbb{P}_{\mathbb{C}}^N\times_{\mathbb{C}}T$, that is, the fiber product of the maps $\mathbb{P}_{\mathbb{C}}^N\to\mathrm{Spec}(\mathbb{C})$ and $\pi\colon\,T\to\mathrm{Spec}(\mathbb{C})$. This product is naturally equipped with the projection $p\colon\,\mathbb{P}_T^N=\mathbb{P}_{\mathbb{C}}^N\times_{\mathbb{C}}T\to T$, so you can think of it as a family of fibers $p^{-1}(t)\simeq\mathbb{P}_{\mathbb{C}}^N$ for each $t\in T$.

Finally, a "family of maps" $f_T\colon\,\mathbb{P}_T^N\to\mathbb{P}_T^N$ is a fancy way of saying "a map $f_T\colon\,\mathbb{P}_T^N\to\mathbb{P}_T^N$ that makes the diagram
$$\begin{array}{ccc}
\mathbb{P}_T^N&\overset{f_T}{\to}&\mathbb{P}_T^N\\
&\searrow&\downarrow\\
&&T
\end{array}$$
commute", where $\mathbb{P}_T^N\to T$ is the projection mentioned above (note that, in category theory, this notion is called "morphism of $T$-schemes", as Cla pointed out). Now the commutativity of the diagram means that for each $t\in T$ the map $f_T$ restricts ("specializes", in your paper) to a map between the fibers $f_t=f_T\vert_{p^{-1}(t)}\colon\, p^{-1}(t)\to p^{-1}(t)$. In that sense, it becomes clear why the terminology "family of maps" is used: indeed, $f_T$ yields a collection of maps $\{f_t\colon\,\mathbb{P}_{\mathbb{C}}^N\to\mathbb{P}_{\mathbb{C}}^N\}_{t\in T}$, as you thought. Nevertheless, $f_T$ is *more than just that*, since it constitutes a map in itself. In other words, it has some additional (algebraic) structure other than just being a collection of maps $\mathbb{P}_{\mathbb{C}}^N\to\mathbb{P}_{\mathbb{C}}^N$ completely unrelated to each other.

Comment: Thank you so much. I believe this is a great explanation.